# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCKDeviceScanner" - Adding Chromecast

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, chromecast

I'm trying to add ChromeCast functionality to my iPhone app, but I get this error when I try to build. I use the sample project (github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-ios) as an example.

This is what I have done:

1. Added GoogleCast.framework to my project.
2. Imported it to my ViewController.h
3. Added GCKDeviceManagerDelegate, GCKMediaControlChannelDelegate to @interface in ViewController.h
4. Added @property deviceScanner and then self.deviceScanner = [[GCKDeviceScanner alloc] init]; to where I create view in ViewController

It is at the last step that build fails.

I have tried to clean and rebuild more times than I can remember. I Have also rolled back the SVN and restarted the process with the same result every time (I added more code in the beginning).

How do you propose I go forward in solving this?

/Björn

Answer (score 0):

If that particular header file is present in the framework folder and the framework is properly linked to the project, you should check whether that framework compiles for i386, you can check this in the Build Settings.

Comment: GCKDeviceScanner.h is part of the framework. How do I verify if the frame work is properly linked? I see the framework in Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries. The framework runs well in the iOS simulator when running the example project from Google.